# How does the iteration over torch.utils.data.DataLoader works?

Tags: python, pytorch, iteration

[Here the image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArYcI.png)

```
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset,batch_size=64,shuffle=True)

import torch.optim as optim
model = NEURAL_NETWORK()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.03)
costfx = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()


def train_model(model,batches):
times = 0
for i in range(batches):
    accuracy = 0
    for image, label in trainloader:
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        output = model(image)
        times += 1
        
        top_p, top_class = output.topk(1, dim=1)

        equals = top_class == label.view(*top_class.shape)
        
        accuracy += torch.mean(equals.type(torch.FloatTensor))
        
        loss = costfx(output,label)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    print("Batch number:{}, train_loss is: {}, accuracy: {}"
          .format(i+1,loss, accuracy/len(trainloader)), times)
```

Since the batch_size is 64 I was expecting that iterating once over the trainload object would have returned times=64 but instead times=938.
Can someone explain why?

Comment: What is `batches` here exactly?

Comment: "In my mind" it meant the number of batch (images) to train the neural network with..hence batches=1-->64 images, batches=5-->320 images etc

Comment: times will show `(no. of samples in dataset / batch size)`. Please check if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

The way data loaders work in PyTorch is quite straightforward. You define a dataset and wrap it with a data loader. This utility function is meant to sample elements from the underlying dataset. A simple usage is to simply set the `batch_size` option: the number of elements per batch. When you iterate over the data loader you will have access, on each iteration loop, to a *single* batch. Each batch containing a number of `batch_size` elements as defined on init.

In your example, if you define `trainloader` as `DataLoader(trainset,batch_size=64,shuffle=True)`, then in your loop:

```
for image, label in trainloader:
    pass
```

Both `image` and `label` will correspond to a *single* batch, with *64* elements each (*64* images and their corresponding labels respectively). This means you do not have to iterate over `range(batches)`. However, you can iterate multiple times over your data loader, this essentially corresponds to epochs:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for image, label in trainloader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(image)
        # ...
```

Comment: Ok, so in your comment you suggested to refer to "epochs" instead of "batches" and thank you for it, I will avoid confusion next time, but my doubt remain: where that 938 comes from and why isn't it a 64?

Comment: You are incrementing over `range(batches)` and `trainloader`, so `i` will end up at around `len(batches)*64`.

Comment: Ok, but I put batches=1, according to what you said hence should be still times=64 I guess isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: And why is my code returning times=938?

Comment: How did you define `batches`?